# Using 3-tap 127/220V to 12V transformer as a poor man's 127V to 220V autotransformer

Tags: transformer, autotransformer

I need to actuate a few contactor switches that need 220VAC in its coils. The problem is, my application is fed by 127VAC. Therefore, I need something like a 10W, 127V to 220V autotransformer.

These are hard to come by. However, 60Hz 127/220V to 12V (1A) transformers are very easy to come by where I live ([here's](https://www.ebay.com/itm/372443193130?hash=item56b7581f2a:g:qd4AAOSwm6VbpBss) something similar to what I am talking about, but with US-appropriate 110/220V inputs).

I would like to use the 3 inputs of the primary windings of one of these transformers (parameters: 60Hz, 127V/220V-to-12V, 1A) as an autotransformer, leaving the secondary windings completely unused. Is there anything that could go wrong?

Comment: Go wrong? It can happen as soon as some other person steps in and starts to assume something which isn't true - a person who thinks there's the same voltage used everywhere and one of the wires is neutral. There can be neutral if it is not connected to the center tap.

Comment: OP could also accidentally short the unused leads and cause the transformer to fry, or drop the transformer on his foot (12VA could hurt a bit, probably 300-400g with pointy edges).

Comment: Protective footwear is strongly advised.

Answer (score 6):

Provided you don't draw too many VA you should be fine. If you stick with the transformer VA rating you'll certainly be fine, so if the coils are rated 10VA it should be okay.

Of course the watts are less than VA for an inductive load like a contactor.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy these autotransformers with DIN rail mount from engineering supply houses, there is no need to make your own (but you may save money making your own)

I would suggest using a 24V transformer because that gives the option to use 24V contactors in the future.